# What's the character encoding used?

Tags: character-encoding, byte

Odd character codes:

> ก็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็ กิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิ ก้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ก็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็ กิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิ ก้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ก็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็ กิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิ ก้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ก็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็ กิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิ ก้้้้้้้้

**Question:** *What's the encoding of these characters?*

(Tip: Try editing this question and you'll see why they're odd, LIVE)

Yeah, that's right. You see the same thing I do. 
Apparently, this came from a mac. So, with the little knowledge of the subject I have, I fired up notepad++ and tried to view it in hex.

The result? Try it yourself: http://notepad-plus-plus.org/

Fairly obvious; What the hell?
I can understand if it is `Just a Bunch of Bits` in some weird proprietary binary encoding (containing stuff like color, font, etc. etc.). But why do they show up so strange?

Also, why do notepad++ not show the original characters from the beginning? If you turn on the hex-editor and then turn it off, it's like it *expands*.

(Also (again), try copy-pasting the above characters *twice* into notepad++. See the difference? Nothing but `0x3f` and the occasional `0x20`. This is also true for each individual character. As far as I know, neither a space nor a question-mark looks like the above characters. But oh, I may be wrong of course..)

Here's a snippet from outlook:

[image: Do you see that?!?!]

**EDIT:** Editing these characters using `UTF-8` instead of stupid `ANSI` actually lets you see the correct bytes.

**EDIT 2:** I probably should have been more clear in what I wanted to know when I wrote the question (in my defence, I was so grossed out I just wanted to scream `BRAINOVERFLOW` when I saw it [the screenshot]).

**EDIT 3:** (copied from yahoo answer)
It appears to be a thing called "stacking diacritics" using Thai characters.

Essentially the Thai character ก "ko kai" can have any of several superscripted diacritic marks such as ็ "maitaikhu". If you follow "ko kai" with "maitaikhu", the latter appears as a superscript thus: ก็

If you put further diacritics after such a combination, they'll stack thus: ก็็็็็

Here are the characters that will do it: http://graphemica.com/search?q=%E0%B8%81…

Comment: This is great, maybe this belongs to meta tough?

Comment: I don't think this is specific to SO.

Comment: That is truly awesome! But also a bit rubbish.

Comment: PizzaPill: No, actually not. It isn't specific to SO; The question is about that string of characters at the top of the question.

Comment: Related: [How do I find out which language some Unicode characters belong to?](http://superuser.com/questions/389333/how-do-i-find-out-which-language-some-unicode-characters-belong-to)

Comment: btw, if you really typed in all that HTML by hand you might want to take a look at the editing help - Markdown is **much** easier.

Comment: AakashM: Well, it isn't that much. It's just a couple of `<br>`.

Comment: @MarcusHansson I just mentally categorized this as a question and as a bug in stackoverflow. It looks crazy but its 100% legal. Unicode ftw.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Easy search on gnome charmap:

```
U+0E01 THAI CHARACTER KO KAI

General Character Properties

In Unicode since: 1.1
Unicode category: Letter, Other

Various Useful Representations

UTF-8: 0xE0 0xB8 0x81
UTF-16: 0x0E01

C octal escaped UTF-8: \340\270\201
XML decimal entity: &#3585;
```

followed by (one or more of / a variation of):

```
U+0E47 THAI CHARACTER MAITAIKHU

General Character Properties

In Unicode since: 1.1
Unicode category: Mark, Non-Spacing

Various Useful Representations

UTF-8: 0xE0 0xB9 0x87
UTF-16: 0x0E47

C octal escaped UTF-8: \340\271\207
XML decimal entity: &#3655;

Annotations and Cross References

Alias names:
 • mai taikhu
```

The second is a non-spacing mark decorating the first char

Comment: The *encoding* is apparently UTF-8, if that's what the OP really wants to know. Maybe Windows has a problem with Thai combining diacritics? On my iPhone, they are overlaid, not stacked like in the screenshot.

Comment: Chrome on linux is hit by the same problem (stacking diacritics) on third, sixth and nineth combination, while it's overlying the other combinations. I think it depends on that the are *many* adjacent diacritics following a character, while probably only one is expected.

Answer (score 4):

Entering those characters in the search box on [Graphmenica](http://graphemica.com/) will take you to [this page](http://graphemica.com/search?q=%E0%B8%81%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87+%E0%B8%81%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4+%E0%B8%81%E0%B9%89%E0%B9%89%E0%B9%89%E0%B9%89%E0%B9%89%E0%B9%89%E0%B9%89%E0%B9%89%E0%B9%89%E0%B9%89%E0%B9%89%E0%B9%89%E0%B9%89%E0%B9%89%E0%B9%89%E0%B9%89%E0%B9%89%E0%B9%89%E0%B9%89%E0%B9%89+%E0%B8%81%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87+%E0%B8%81%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4+%E0%B8%81%E0%B9%89%E0%B9%89%E0%B9%89%E0%B9%89%E0%B9%89%E0%B9%89%E0%B9%89%E0%B9%89%E0%B9%89%E0%B9%89%E0%B9%89%E0%B9%89%E0%B9%89%E0%B9%89%E0%B9%89%E0%B9%89%E0%B9%89%E0%B9%89%E0%B9%89%E0%B9%89+%E0%B8%81%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87+%E0%B8%81%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4+%E0%B8%81%E0%B9%89%E0%B9%89%E0%B9%89%E0%B9%89%E0%B9%89%E0%B9%89%E0%B9%89%E0%B9%89%E0%B9%89%E0%B9%89%E0%B9%89%E0%B9%89%E0%B9%89%E0%B9%89%E0%B9%89%E0%B9%89%E0%B9%89%E0%B9%89%E0%B9%89%E0%B9%89+%E0%B8%81%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87%E0%B9%87+%E0%B8%81%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4%E0%B8%B4+%E0%B8%81%E0%B9%89%E0%B9%89%E0%B9%89%E0%B9%89%E0%B9%89%E0%B9%89%E0%B9%89%E0%B9%89), showing the different characters being used:

- [ก  thai character ko kai (Unicode code point: U+0E01)](http://graphemica.com/%E0%B8%81)
- [ิ  thai character sara i (Unicode code point: U+0E34)](http://graphemica.com/0E34)
- [็  thai character maitaikhu (Unicode code point: U+0E47)](http://graphemica.com/0E47)
- [้  thai character mai tho (Unicode code point: U+0E49)](http://graphemica.com/0E49)