# How can I decode unicode characters like this?

Tags: unicode, character-encoding

Maybe a stupid question but I like to decode these kind of unicode characters. How do I do it?

> ۫ͫ̈́̊̃͛͐̎̂̓̃̇͛̍ͪͩ́͒͆̓̉̽̍̏͂ͮ̈́ͦ̀ͤ͗̅͗̄̐̃ͬͮͣͩͮ̆̓́͛ͯͤͣͧ̔ͮ̈́ͯ̅۫ͫ̈́̊̃͛͐̎̂̓̃̇͛̍ͪͩ́͒͆̓̉̽̍̏͂ͮ̈́ͦ̀ͤ͗̅͗̄̐̃ͬͮͣͩͮ̆̓́͛ͯͤͣͧ̔ͮ̈́ͯ̅۫ͫ̈́̊̃͛͐̎̂̓̃̇͛̍ͪͩ́͒͆̓̉̽̍̏͂ͮ̈́ͦ̀ͤ͗̅͗̄̐̃ͬͮͣͩͮ̆̓́͛ͯͤͣͧ̔ͮ̈́ͯ̅۫ͫ̈́̊̃͛͐̎̂̓̃̇͛̍ͪͩ́͒͆̓̉̽̍̏͂ͮ̈́ͦ̀ͤ͗̅͗̄̐̃ͬͮͣͩͮ̆̓́͛ͯͤͣͧ̔ͮ̈́ͯ̅۫ͫ̈́̊̃͛͐̎̂̓̃̇̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚
>   ۫ͫ̈́̊̃͛͐̎̂̓̃̇͛̍ͪͩ́͒͆̓̉̽̍̏͂ͮ̈́ͦ̀ͤ͗̅͗̄̐̃ͬͮͣͩͮ̆̓́͛ͯͤͣͧ̔ͮ̈́ͯ̅۫ͫ̈́̊̃͛͐̎̂̓̃̇͛̍ͪͩ́͒͆̓̉̽̍̏͂ͮ̈́ͦ̀ͤ͗̅͗̄̐̃ͬͮͣͩͮ̆̓́͛ͯͤͣͧ̔ͮ̈́ͯ̅۫ͫ̈́̊̃͛͐̎̂̓̃̇͛̍ͪͩ́͒͆̓̉̽̍̏͂ͮ̈́ͦ̀ͤ͗̅͗̄̐̃ͬͮͣͩͮ̆̓́͛ͯͤͣͧ̔ͮ̈́ͯ̅۫ͫ̈́̊̃͛͐̎̂̓̃̇͛̍ͪͩ́͒͆̓̉̽̍̏͂ͮ̈́ͦ̀ͤ͗̅͗̄̐̃ͬͮͣͩͮ̆̓́͛ͯͤͣͧ̔ͮ̈́ͯ̅۫ͫ̈́̊̃͛͐̎̂̓̃̇̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚

I like to be able to decode them into /uXXXX syntax so I can use them for instance in a web page...

Comment: Ermmm.... what? What do you mean - "decode"?

Comment: At least tell us where it comes from, and where it will be decoded.

Comment: I have a document with it in and I like to use some of it in a web page with \u0183 syntax. But I cant get a grip of the characters.

Comment: Do you need to? Just set the webpage to UTF-8, edit it in an editor that supports UTF-8, and simply copy-paste the characters as-is.

Comment: Thanks but I like to produce them by iteration...

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the character encoding used?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9310177/whats-the-character-encoding-used)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using windows you can try copying and pasting that into the character map application.

Comment: @jtheman On OS X you can enable the menu that shows different keyboard layouts and that menu can also contain a character panel. Paste the characters into the search field of that panel and it will show all the characters to you.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ (with an implementation that supports C++11, such as is included in Xcode):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <cstdint>

int main() {
    std::u32string s = U"ͫ̈́̊̃͛͐̎̂̓̃̇͛̍ͪͩ́͒͆̓̉̽̍̏͂ͮ̈́ͦ̀ͤ͗̅͗̄̐̃ͬͮͣͩͮ̆̓́͛ͯͤͣͧ̔ͮ̈́ͯ̅۫ͫ̈́̊̃͛͐̎̂̓̃̇͛̍ͪͩ́͒͆̓̉̽̍̏͂ͮ̈́ͦ̀ͤ͗̅͗̄̐̃ͬͮͣͩͮ̆̓́͛ͯͤͣͧ̔ͮ̈́ͯ̅۫ͫ̈́̊̃͛͐̎̂̓̃̇͛̍ͪͩ́͒͆̓̉̽̍̏͂ͮ̈́ͦ̀ͤ͗̅͗̄̐̃ͬͮͣͩͮ̆̓́͛ͯͤͣͧ̔ͮ̈́ͯ̅۫ͫ̈́̊̃͛͐̎̂̓̃̇͛̍ͪͩ́͒͆̓̉̽̍̏͂ͮ̈́ͦ̀ͤ͗̅͗̄̐̃ͬͮͣͩͮ̆̓́͛ͯͤͣͧ̔ͮ̈́ͯ̅۫ͫ̈́̊̃͛͐̎̂̓̃̇̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚̚";

    std::cout.fill('0');
    std::cout << std::hex;

    for (auto c : s)
        std::cout << "\\u" << std::setw(4) << static_cast<std::uint_least32_t>(c);
}
```